# C# Xamarin Java.Interop error?

Tags: java, c#, xamarin

Hello since the last `Xamarin update` we get this `error`.

> CS0012 The type 'IJavaPeerable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Java.Interop, Version=0.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'.  ImageLibrary    C:\Users\rutge\Source\Repos\GarderobeApp\ImageSwiper\ImageSwiper.cs 33  Active

Does anybody have an idea what this means?

Comment: Can you post the code where you are getting this error? I remember getting these errors in my Android project a year ago. I am pretty sure you need to inherit some behavior from a certain class defined in the library that is referenced in the error message.

Comment: Visual Studio will prompt you to add that reference.

Answer (score 29):

You can found it here

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Java.Interop.dll

then :

1. Go to your Android project
2. Right Click in reference and choose "Add Reference"
3. Browse file location
4. Add and done

if you still get error, try to rebuild your project

Comment: Suppose you are building on a Mac?

Comment: I do not have this subfolder under Microsoft\Framework\...
Why is that?

Comment: On Mac can find Java.Interop at following path: ‎⁨Macintosh HD⁩ ▸ ⁨Library⁩ ▸ ⁨Frameworks⁩ ▸ ⁨Xamarin.Android.framework⁩ ▸ ⁨Versions⁩ ▸ ⁨9.0.0-20⁩ ▸ ⁨lib⁩ ▸ ⁨xamarin.android⁩ ▸ ⁨xbuild-frameworks⁩ ▸ ⁨MonoAndroid⁩ ▸ ⁨v1.0⁩

Answer (score 8):

I go the same error after the last update.
You just have to add the reference to Java.Interop to resolve the problem.

1. Go to your Android project
2. Right Click in reference and choose "Add Reference"
3. On Assembly, look for Java.Interop and add it
4. Rebuild your project

If you need some screenshots, I can provide them later.

Comment: I still have this issue event when the Java.Interop has been added as a reference. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Forget that, my mistake, I had accidentally added the file to a PCL project rather than the Android one.

Answer (score 6):

In my case it was a bit different, I couldn't find monoandroid folder in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.
```

So on further I searched and found it in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid
```

This might be the case with someone else.

Comment: Thanks! All others didn't work for me (maybe it changed?). Worked after adding Mono.Android.Export.dll in MonoAndroid\2.3 folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can hover over the offending line and see the missing DLL.

[image: Line complaining about missing reference]

Now add the missing reference;

1. Open the Solution Explorer, and within References right click, and select *Add Reference*[image: Add Reference from Solution Explorer]
2. Within the Reference Manager click Browse, and Browse again.
   [image: Add reference]
3. In the file dialog copy and paste this path:

   C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\

[image: Go to DLL path]

Click Java.Interop.dll

[image: Add file]

4. Okay the Reference Manager

Answer (score 1):

You can directly copy the assembly `Java.Interop.dll` from the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0` to the `bin/Debug` folder of your project to resolve the issue.

This procedure perfectly worked for me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

These errors are not due to a problem with the solution or the references.  They are a by-product of other changes that seem to confuse tools like `ReSharper`.  At least this is correct in my case, my solution still compiles and functions without manually referencing any Reference Assemblies.

There is a Xamarin bug report for this but they determined this to be an external issue with `ReSharper` as per my experience.

Rather than manually adding references to the project you can also tell ReSharper to simply ignore the errors by opening:

```
ReSharper -> Windows -> Solution Errors
```

And then ignoring the issues here.

Answer (score 0):

In my case iOS and Android use the seem Business Layer when I run my android application works ok but when I run iOS show me the error You must add a reference to assembly 'Java.Interop, Version=0.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'

The problem: I was using JSONObject from Org.Json

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/org.json.jsonobject?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9

this dll just work with android

I need change for JsonObject from System.Json

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.json.jsonobject?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.1

That was my solution, now my two applications work

Answer (score 0):

If you still can't find Java.Interop, then search for "Java.Interop" in your search bar inside C: drive and add it as a reference to your project.