# Java.Interop Xamarin Forms C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Java.Interop, Version=0.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'Java.Interop.dll'
   at Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() CameraApps3.Droid
```

Error when debugging. I've refered to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37802076/5332955 but I cant find the Java.Interop.dll in my folder. Any ideas why the error and suggestion for other solutions? Tq

I'm using MVSP2015

Comment: Try `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Java.Interop.dll`

Comment: I've search the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\`, but didn't find it. Any ideas why?

Comment: Sorry no, not quire sure why is it missing

Comment: On Mac can find Java.Interop at following path: ‎⁨Macintosh HD⁩ ▸ ⁨Library⁩ ▸ ⁨Frameworks⁩ ▸ ⁨Xamarin.Android.framework⁩ ▸ ⁨Versions⁩ ▸ ⁨9.0.0-20⁩ ▸ ⁨lib⁩ ▸ ⁨xamarin.android⁩ ▸ ⁨xbuild-frameworks⁩ ▸ ⁨MonoAndroid⁩ ▸ ⁨v1.0⁩

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem until last day. I just asked someone with the java.interop.dll file to send it to me so I can add it as a reference in my app.

I upload the file for u so u can use it if u don't know someone around u with the file. U can download it from [this link](https://www.mediafire.com/?6yo0oertnoqe9bl).

Also after fixing this error I got some other java related errors, so I downloaded latest JDK available and added it to my xamarin. after that all my problems were fixed and I could work on my app problem-free.

Hope I could help.